# PHP Sender email address as email title

Tags: php, html, css

When we receive messages through our site, the 'sender' of the email is listed as "newwavea@host424.hostmonster.com", rather than the address of the person who submitted a message.
Could you check my PHP and see where I've gone wrong? Thanks.
Here's the [WEBPAGE LINK](http://new-wave-academy.com/Contact/contact.html)

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['full-name1']) or !empty($_POST['email1']) ) {
    header('Location: success.html');
}

$name = $_POST['full-name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: SSR'; 
$to = 'info@new-wave-academy.com'; // send to this address
$subject = $_POST['subject'];

$body = "From: $name\n
Email: $email\n 
Message:\n $message";

mail($to, $subject, $body); 
header("Location: http://new-wave-academy.com/Contact/success.html"); /* Redirect browser */
exit();
?>
```

Comment: The sender *shouldn't be* the address of the person who submitted a message. Use "Reply-To" for that.

Comment: @AlexHowansky thanks for the reply. how would I implement 'reply-to'?

Answer (score 0):

`From` and `Return-path` addresses must be set explicitly. PHP will not parse the message body looking for them (why should it?). Since you aren't setting any, the system will simply use default value set in server config.

You can use the `$additional_headers` parameter for sender and, in many numbers, you can use `$additional_parameters` for the return address:

> `bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, mixed $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )`

([reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php))

Beware though that the underlying mail transport service may or may not allow arbitrary addresses in these fields.

It's also very easy to screw the message format with `mail()` so I strongly recommend a third party library like [Swift Mailer](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/) or [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: I'm very grateful for your reply but I'm a complete PHP novice and basically have no clue how to do what you're saying

Comment: Then I strongly suggest you just install one of the libraries (PHPMailer is possibly more newbie friendly, but both are good) and configure it with the basic usage documentation they have. `mail()` is very difficult to use correctly, even for advanced programmers.

Comment: Is there not a quicker way for me to do it myself? surely I'm missing about 2 or 3 lines of code here. my client just wants the name of the person to display as 'sender' when the messages come in, instead of the long host server email.